# setInterval() causes images to change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I've made some Marquees using CSS animations, as well as a countdown timer. The Marquees are populated with 100 random images and move, alternating, form left to right and right to left.
However, every time the timer reduces, the marquee images change, but they keep scrolling uninterrupted, and I'm not sure why. How can I stop this behaviour?

Code:

```
function CatchTwo({ score, setScore, setActiveGame }) {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(15);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer =
      counter > 0 && setInterval(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [counter]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function endGame() {
      if (counter === 0) {
        // setActiveGame("newGame");
        return;
      }
    }

    endGame();
  }, [counter, setActiveGame]);

  const images = () => {
    const imgUrls = [apple, cookie, croissant, doughnut, kiwi];
    const imgArray = [];

    const clickHandler = (e) => {
      if (e.target.currentSrc.search("cookie") > 0) {
        console.log("cookie found");
      }
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      const rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

      imgArray.push(
        <img
          key={i}
          onClick={clickHandler}
          className="Marquee__image"
          src={imgUrls[rndInt - 1]}
          alt="food icon"
        />
      );
    }

    return imgArray;
  };

  return (
    <section className="Marquee">
      <div className="Marquee__stats">
        <p className="Marquee__stats-score">Score: {score}</p>
        <p className="Marquee__stats-time">Time left: {counter}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="Marquee__scrollContainer">
        <div className="Marquee__scrollText-ltr">{images()}</div>
        <div className="Marquee__scrollText-rtl">{images()}</div>
        <div className="Marquee__scrollText-ltr">{images()}</div>
        <div className="Marquee__scrollText-rtl">{images()}</div>
        <div className="Marquee__scrollText-ltr">{images()}</div>
        <div className="Marquee__scrollText-rtl">{images()}</div>
        <div className="Marquee__scrollText-ltr">{images()}</div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default CatchTwo;
```

Comment: That's what you expect to happen when you don't store your image array across renders

Answer (score 0):

To stop this behavior you can store your images array in state with the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook at the top of your function
`const [images, setImages] = useState([]);`
and then you can modify that array.

Comment: I tried this by adding the state, and changing all mentions of "imgArray" to setImages, and changed the .push() to setImages([<img...>]);. I'm not sure if this is correct, but, I'm getting the error: `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

Comment: @amputator Oh, I see, your goal is to create 7 arrays with a 100 items each, and display them, correct?

Comment: Yep, that's it. I figured out a solution by moving the timer, and, thus, the setInterval, into its own component and calling it here.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution:
The timer was was causing the page to re-render so I made it into its own component and called it instead of `<p className="Marquee__stats-time">Time left: {counter}</p>`. This allowed just the countdown to re-render every second, fixing the issue.